# Radio buttons aren't disabled after submission & cannot unselect selected radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I haven't worked with forms much and am trying to get this form to be able to select more than 1 radio button per time (which it currently can, but you then cannot unselect one if it's already selected) and then submit the rows with radios selected (if that makes sense). And then once a row has been submitted, be then unable to select the radio input for that row.

Not sure why, but the radio buttons that are selected before clicking submit aren't then added the `disabled='disabled'` attribute after clicking submit. Does anyone know why? And how can it be fixed?

Thanks for any help here.

```js
function submitForm() {
  var radioOne = $("#one"),
      radioTwo = $("#two"),
      radioThree = $("#three"),
      theForm = $("#theForm");
  
  alert('Form will submit');
  //theForm.submit();

  if (radioOne.checked = true) {
    radioOne.attr('disabled','disabled');
  }

  if (radioTwo.checked = true) {
    radioTwo.attr('disabled','disabled');
  }

  if (radioThree.checked = true) {
    radioThree.attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row norwap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='theForm'>
  <div>
    <p>Detail 1</p>
    <p>Detail 2</p>
    <input type="radio" name="one" id="one" value="one" /><label for="one">One</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Detail 1</p>
    <p>Detail 2</p>
    <input type="radio" name="two" id="two" value="two" /><label for="two">Two</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Detail 1</p>
    <p>Detail 2</p>
    <input type="radio" name="three" id="three" value="three" /><label for="three">Three</label>
  </div>

  <button onclick='submitForm()'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: When a form submits back to itself, essentially the page is loading again back to the original state, so what you have to do is have code that, when the page loads, reads  these values so you can update the display.  Are you using any server-side language for this?

Comment: I've just commented out the form submit line for now, but it still does the same. There's no server-side language for this and is just a test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  I've changed around some things but this should do what you want.  But as I went over the code, your biggest mistake was checking for equality with "=" when it should be "==" or "===".

**Update**

As requested, radio buttons will now function like checkboxes so by clicking them when they're clicked, they will then become unclicked.  This is all in $('input[type="radio"]').click

```js
$("button").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var radioOne = $("#one"),
      radioTwo = $("#two"),
      radioThree = $("#three"),
      theForm = $("#theForm");
  
  alert('Form will submit');
  //theForm.submit();

  if (radioOne.is(":checked")) {
    radioOne.attr('disabled','disabled');
  }

  if (radioTwo.is(":checked")) {
    radioTwo.attr('disabled','disabled');
  }

  if (radioThree.is(":checked")) {
    radioThree.attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
});

$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var isChecked = $this.attr('isChecked');
  if (isChecked == 'true'){
    $this.attr('isChecked', 'false');
    $this.prop("checked", false);
  } else {
    $this.attr('isChecked', 'true');
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row norwap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='theForm'>
  <div>
    <p>Detail 1</p>
    <p>Detail 2</p>
    <input type="radio" name="one" id="one" value="one" /><label for="one">One</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Detail 1</p>
    <p>Detail 2</p>
    <input type="radio" name="two" id="two" value="two" /><label for="two">Two</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Detail 1</p>
    <p>Detail 2</p>
    <input type="radio" name="three" id="three" value="three" /><label for="three">Three</label>
  </div>

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you, that is very helpful! And to see your version compared to mine. Just one thing: is it possible to make it so that whenever a radio button is clicked on, can it be clicked on again to deselect it? other than that, your solution is perfect!

Comment: Sure, but for that type of interaction you describe, why not use a checkbox?  You have 3 radio buttons that can all be checked off at the same time, so I'm a little puzzled as to why you're using radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: that's a very good point. It was tasked to me as using radio buttons, so is this actually possible? I'll raise the point of using checkboxes though. This entire question and demo is actually practice in my own time for a new job.

Comment: Personally I would go for the checkboxes, but I updated my code to show how to make radio buttons function as a checkbox, so you're covered.